# Pandas How to flag consecutive values ignoring the first occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, flags

I have the following code:

```
data={'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
  'value':[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0]}
  df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
  df
  Out[8]: 
      id  value
 0    1      1
 1    2      0
 2    3      1
 3    4      0
 4    5      1
 5    6      1
 6    7      1
 7    8      0
 8    9      0
 9    10     1
10    11     0
```

I want to create a flag column that indicate with 1 consecutive values starting from the second occurrence and ignoring the first.

With the actual solution:

```
df['flag'] = 
df.value.groupby([df.value,df.flag.diff().ne(0).cumsum()]).transform('size').ge(3).astype(int)


Out[8]: 
        id  value  flag
    0    1      1     0
    1    2      0     0
    2    3      1     0
    3    4      0     0
    4    5      1     1
    5    6      1     1
    6    7      1     1
    7    8      0     1
    8    9      0     1
    9    10     1     0
   10    11     0     0
```

While I need a solution like this, where the first occurence is flagged as 0 and 1 starting from the second:

```
Out[8]: 
        id  value  flag
    0    1      1    0
    1    2      0    0
    2    3      1    0
    3    4      0    0
    4    5      1    0
    5    6      1    1
    6    7      1    1
    7    8      0    0
    8    9      0    1
    9    10     1    0
   10    11     0    0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create consecutive groups by compared [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values by not equal and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), create counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and compare if greater values like `0` by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html), last map `True, False` to `1, 0` by casting to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['flag'] = (df.groupby(df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift()).cumsum())
                .cumcount()
                .gt(0)
                .astype(int))
print (df)
    id  value  flag
0    1      1     0
1    2      0     0
2    3      1     0
3    4      0     0
4    5      1     0
5    6      1     1
6    7      1     1
7    8      0     0
8    9      0     1
9   10      1     0
10  11      0     0
```

How it working:

```
print (df.assign(g = df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift()).cumsum(),
                 counter = df.groupby(df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount(),
                 mask = df.groupby(df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount().gt(0)))

    id  value  g  counter   mask
0    1      1  1        0  False
1    2      0  2        0  False
2    3      1  3        0  False
3    4      0  4        0  False
4    5      1  5        0  False
5    6      1  5        1   True
6    7      1  5        2   True
7    8      0  6        0  False
8    9      0  6        1   True
9   10      1  7        0  False
10  11      0  8        0  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and a custom grouper:

```
# group by identical successive values
grp = df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift()).cumsum()

# flag all but the first one (>0)
# convert the booleans True/False to integers 1/0
df['flag'] = df.groupby(grp).cumcount().gt(0).astype(int)
```

Generic code to skip first `N`:

```
N = 1

grp = df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift()).cumsum()
df['flag'] = df.groupby(grp).cumcount().ge(N).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    id  value  flag
0    1      1     0
1    2      0     0
2    3      1     0
3    4      0     0
4    5      1     0
5    6      1     1
6    7      1     1
7    8      0     0
8    9      0     1
9   10      1     0
10  11      0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.assign(flag=df.value.diff().eq(0).astype(int))
```

out：

```
    id  value  flag
0    1      1     0
1    2      0     0
2    3      1     0
3    4      0     0
4    5      1     0
5    6      1     1
6    7      1     1
7    8      0     0
8    9      0     1
9   10      1     0
10  11      0     0
```